# How to mock a component within an Enzyme Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to set the props of a component within my shallow rendered enzyme component.

**Parent.jsx**

```
import Child from './Child';

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child disabled={true}/>
      <Child disabled={true}/>
      <Child disabled={true}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my tests, I now want to mock this all instances of this`<Child/>` component with custom props e.g `disabled={false}`

**Parent.test.jsx**

```
 import Parent from './Parent'
 import Child from './Child'

 const wrapper = shallow(<Parent/>)

 // Set all instances of <Child/> within this wrapper to <Child disabled={false}/>
```

I've tried to use [setProps](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.html) but get `ShallowWrapper::setProps() can only be called on the root`.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: `shallow` doesn't look for child elements

Comment: Ah okay, thanks @underscore - I will use `mount` instead and see if it works